# Python subproces ignores input files for command

Tags: python, windows, terminal

I need to run an SQL script from python and have constructed code that generates a command to run a SQL script.

```
import subprocess
command_to_run_script = 'psql {0} < my_sql_script.sql'.format(
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
    )
subprocess.check_output(command_to_run_script)
```

When I run this script I get the following:

```
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "my_sql_script.sql" ignored
```

And the command

```
psql {SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI}
```

is run. Any idea how to make the script run correctly(when I copy paste it directly to the consol it works).

Comment: You should split each of the command arguments into a separate element of a list.   Try `subprocess.run(['psql', SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, '<', 'my_sql_script.sql'])`

Comment: You are using a redirect (`>`). That is a shell operation. Set `shell=True` in your `subprocess` call.

Comment: Thank you very much @BoarGules would you make it into an offical answer such that I can give you credit for the answer.